# I cannot connect to rails server. localhost:3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I just using AWS, EC2.

and I run server but I cannot access localhost:3000.

I tried

```
rails server -b0.0.0.0
rails server -b(AWS public host)
```

how can I access to server...??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DCj9z.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes `rails server -b 0.0.0.0` is correct, you should be able to access it from the outside on port 3000 if your AWS environment is set up correctly (hint, check firewalls etc),

on the other hand, why would you use port 3000 to access an AWS hosted web service from the outside is a completely different matter

Comment: I tried -b 0.0.0.0 but it wasn't work at the other place.
but in my home.
it works.... why??

Comment: Because there is probably a firewall preventing you

Answer (score 0):

On your screenshot, you are not trying to reach "localhost" but your public IP. Can you try http://localhost:3000 while running rails server -b 0.0.0.0?

To access your public IP, I assume that your machine is accessible publicaly on port 22 since you ssh'd in it. So just make sure that you have opened your security group on port 3000 (and also that you don't have any DENY ACL on your subnet, but this should be OK by default if you didn't touch the ACL rules).

Comment: I tried -b 0.0.0.0 but it wasn't work at the other place.
but in my home.
it works.... why??

Comment: Check your security groups at the AWS level, as suggested in my answere